# Action Event does not respect the branch and other events

Tags: github-actions

I use **MonoRepo** on **Github** for its `frontend` and `backend`, where I control the `tests` and `deploys` for each one.

At the moment I have **two actions**, which are: `deploys.yml` and `tests.yml`.

`deploys.yml` deploys the given project with some conditionals and `tests.yml` does a battery of tests with some conditionals.

**What I'm trying to do is this:**

The `deploys.yml` action can only be activated, in the main branch and when it is only a `closed` `pull_request` and when the `tests.yml` action is finished. Each job will be for a specific project, so I need to know the source branch that was `merged`, for example, from `frontend-develop` to `main` or `backend-develop` to `main`.

The `tests.yml` action can only be activated with `push` to only both branchs develops and when it is an `open` or `edit` `pull_request` on the `main` branch.

**What problem is occurring?**

The `deploys.yml` action is waiting for `tests.yml` to finish **(which is correct)**, but it is running even when I `push` the `frontend-develop` branch, in which case it should only run when there is a `pull_request` for the `main` branch and after the `tests.yml`.

**TESTS.YML:**

```
name: PIPELINE OF TESTS

on:
  push:
    branches: [frontend-develop, backend-develop]
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, edited]
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  test-frontend:
    if: ${{ github.head_ref == 'frontend-develop' || github.ref == 'refs/heads/frontend-develop' }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./frontend
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]
        architecture: [x64]
    steps:
      - name: CHECK-OUT GIT REPOSITORY
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: USE NODEJS ${{ matrix.node-version }} - ${{ matrix.architecture }}
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2

      - name: INSTALL PROJECT DEPENDENCIES (YARN)
        run: yarn

      - name: CODE ANALYSE (LINT) AND STYLE-GUIDE ANALYSE (PRETTIER + AIRBNB)
        run: yarn lint-check

      - name: UNIT TEST (JEST)
        run: yarn test
```

**DEPLOYS.YML:**

```
name: PIPELINE OF DEPLOYS

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["PIPELINE OF TESTS"]
    branches: [main]
    types: [completed]

  pull_request:
    types: [closed]
    branches: [main]

jobs:
  deploy-frontend:
    if: ${{ github.event.workflow_run.conclusion == 'success' && github.head_ref == 'frontend-develop' }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./frontend
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [14.x]
        architecture: [x64]
    steps:
      - name: CHECKOUT GIT REPOSITORY
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: VERCEL FRONTEND DEPLOY TO PRODUCTION
        uses: amondnet/vercel-action@v20
        with:
          vercel-token: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}
          github-token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          vercel-args: "--prod"
          vercel-org-id: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_ORG_ID}}
          vercel-project-id: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_PROJECT_ID}}
```